# How to check if i properly parsed through the JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

This is my first time calling an API and parsing through the JSON output. I know I called the API and retrieved the data since I printed it onto the console but I now want to print out a certain part of the JSON for example: all the titles of the list (if it had titles and some other information).

```
  public async Task MainAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient()) //creates a new client that will make the call to the api.  
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear(); 
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); // Accepts header for JSON format
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/api/api_GET/?key=MYKEYGOESHERE&commodity_desc=CORN&year__GE=2012&state_alpha=VA&format=JSON");                                                                                         
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(contents);

                    //List<quickStats> quickStat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<quickStats>>(contents);
                    quickStats quickStat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<quickStats>(contents);

                    Console.WriteLine("Done");

                    foreach(var item in quickStat)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.source_desc);
                    }
                     
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                //Console.WriteLine("test");
            }
        }
        

    }
}


class quickStats
 {
   public String source_desc { get; set; }
 }
```

The JSON isn't in an array so I can't create a list like in the commented line then do a foreach statement for that list, following this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkB-cIMjXGQ

I am wondering how else I can print the parsed list of "source_desc".
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the valid api? I received unauthorized when calling the above api.

Comment: If the response is a consistent structure, can you cast it as a defined object? You can do what you like with it after that.

Comment: @Tomato32 Each key is personalized to an email so I purposely left it out, didn't think it was needed.

Comment: Then create a mock-up that has the same structure. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It's structure like this

```
{"data":[
{"source_desc": "XXXX"}, 
{"source_desc": "OOOO"}, 
{"source_desc": "TTTT"}
]}
```

so your serialization class should be defined as:

```
class quickStats
{
   public List<quickStatsDetail> data { get; set; }
}

class quickStatsDetail
{
   public String source_desc { get; set; }
}
```